# Angular - How to implement error.errors in Angular-11

Tags: angular

I have this Angular-11 code

```
errorHandler(error){
    this.notify.clear();
    console.log(error);
    if(error.errors && error.errors.email){
      this.error = error.errors.email;
    }
    else if(error.message=="Unauthorized"){
      this.error = null;
      this.notify.error("Invalid Login Details or email not confirmed", {timeout:0})
    } else {
      this.error = null;
      this.notify.error(error.message, {timeout:0})
    }
  }
```

I had written it in Angular-7.

How do I re-write to transform the whole function to Angular-11, especially the error.errors

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try with this approach

```
errorHandler(error) {  
    let errorMessage = '';
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // client-side error
            errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
        } else {
            // server-side error
            errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
        }
        console.log(errorMessage);
        return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
```